# Multiple joins using active record with YII framework

Tags: sql, activerecord, yii

im getting stuck with active record for yii.

im using models for each table in my db.

the sql i try to get is querying and joining from 3 tables.

what i want to accomplish is the equivalent of the sql command :

```
   SELECT  location_code as stopkey, bay_no bay_no, description stop_name, route_area_code route_area_code, latitude latitude, longitude, build_code build_code, message_time message_time, ip_address ip_address, route.route_code route, make make, last_impact last_impact, impact_count impact_count, last_bootup last_bootup, bootup_count bootup_count, last_active_hour last_active_hour, last_active_day last_active_day, operator.operator_code operator_code, routes routes, bearing  
                FROM snapshot_stop_status route
                JOIN  route_visibility ON route.route_id = route_visibility.route_id
                JOIN  operator ON operator.operator_id = route_visibility.operator_id
                WHERE usernm = 'me'

    ORDER BY  location_code
```

here is what i tried so far :

```
 public function relations() {

            return array(
              'RoutesVisibility' =>array(self::MANY_MANY,'route_visibility','route_id'),

            );
        }
```

How can i accomplish this using relations function in the models ?

any kind of help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

route_visibility is the joining table that tie operator to snapshot_stop_status. So in yii you can specify the table doing the relations:

```
'operators' =>array(self::MANY_MANY,'Operator','route_visibility(route_id,operator_id )'),
```

And in Operator:

```
'routes' =>array(self::MANY_MANY,'Route','route_visibility(operator_id, route_id)'),
```

Then you can request with something like:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = array('operators' => array('condition' => 'usernm = "me"'));
$models => Route:model()->findAll($criteria);
```